# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on PDO statement

Tags: mysql, pdo

my function of pdo is:

```
public function viewBookReceiveByDate($startDate,$endDate){     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `book_receive_store` WHERE `ActualDate` BETWEEN  :startDate AND :endDate";

    $statement = $this -> dbo -> prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':startDate',$startDate);
    $statement->bindParam(':endDate',$endDate);
    $statement -> execute();
    $statement -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'BookReceive');

    $resultSet = array();
    while ($row = $statement -> fetch()) {
        $resultSet[] = $row;
    }
    return $resultSet;
}
```

and my database is like:

```
ID
EntryDate
ActualDate
ReferenceNo
BindingCode
BookCode
ProductQuantity
ProductType
```

where `ActualDate`="2013.11.01","2013.11.05" etc

Now when I try to select the data from date range in my controller file:

```
$bookReceiveManager = new BookReceiveManager();
            $getBookList = $bookReceiveManager->viewBookReceiveByDate($startDate, $endDate);
            //print_r($getBookList);
            foreach($getBookList as $recBookookList): endforeach;
```

Its shows the error:

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\kbl_mis\reports\product_receive_report_ajax.php on line 27"

what to do now?

Comment: This code cannot cause such an error. You are getting it somewhere else

Comment: Are you using a MySQL.  If so, you've got your start and end date in the wrong format. ActualDate="2013-11-01","2013-11-05"

Comment: well I can't solve or estimate that's why I need help! Do you need any more details to ans me?

Comment: ya I am using mysql. and at php end while inserting actual date I use date function like: date("YY.mm.dd")
When I run the same query directly it give an result at mysql admin. Now do I need to change this format?

Comment: Where you're selecting dates, use a hyphen instead of a dot for the date input

Comment: AdRock so I suppose have to use date("YY-mm-dd") instead of date("YY.mm.dd")?

Comment: We need only **REAL code you run**. Try to concentrate and post the actual code here. Such an action require no special skills. What is the real code for viewBookReceiveByDate()? What is line 27 in product_receive_report_ajax.php?

Comment: @YourCommonSense
viewBookReceiveByDate($startDate, $endDate) is a function where I fetch the query and which is given at my 1st query!(I can't understand how you miss the 1st function!)
$startDate & $endDate are two constructors where
$startdate="2013.11.06" & $endDate="2013.11.08" 
was this for you give me a (-) ?

Comment: For posting not a real code. viewBookReceiveByDate() you posted here will **always** return valid agrument for foreach - thus it cannot cause this error

Comment: Yes, use date("Y-m-d")

Comment: You could put your code in a try/catch block and it should tell you the error today with the query.... try { //your code here } catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}

Comment: Thanks @AdRock. Trying as you suggest.

Comment: YourCommonSense I also surprised like you after the error. But as ADRock suggest me, I think that's  the problem.